# How to fix compiler error

Tags: xcode, cocoa, gcc

ALL,
I created .mm file in my XCode project alone with .h file and put following code there:

```
#pragma once
class Speech
{
public:
    Speech();
private:
    NSSpeechSynthesizer *m_speech;
};
```

and

```
#import <AppKit/NSSpeechSynthesizer.h>
#include "speech.h"

Speech::Speech()
{
     m_speech = [NSSpeechSynthesizer new];
}
```

During compilation I'm getting an error: "ISO C++ forbids declaring NSSpeechSynthesizer with no type".

I need to somehow include the NSSpeechSynthesizer.h file but whatever I tried - nothing works.

Can someone please help?

[EDIT]
It looks like I need to somehow make the path to the header available in XCode, or just make XCode aware that I will use an appropriate framework..
[/EDIT]

Comment: I am not into XCode, but it seems that the compiler does not know `NSSpeechSynthesizer` - where is this defined? Are you missing any header file?

Comment: your 2nd listing is not C++, yet the compiler says it thinks it is. Try changing the source type to Objective C

Comment: You don't say in which line you get the compilation error, in the first file or the second. My guess is it's the bottommost one, but you really should say so explicitly.

Comment: @Adam Is `m_speech = [NSSpeechSynthesizer new];` correct in Objective C?

Comment: You declare private instance var in `.h` file where the compiler does not know yet what `NSSpeechSynthesizer` is. Try moving `import` statement for speech synthesizer to `.h` instead of `.mm` file.

Comment: @Adam, the file type is .mm which is Objective-C++.

Comment: @Mr.Lister, the error is in the header file and it points to the pointer declaration.

Comment: @Eimantas, Doing that yields 170 errors in the NSObjRuntime.h. ;-) And the original error is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try forward declaring `NSSpeechSynthesizer`, just as you would do with a pure Objective-C solution:

```
#pragma once
class NSSpeechSynthesizer;    // Added
class Speech
{
public:
    Speech();
private:
    NSSpeechSynthesizer *m_speech;
};
```

Comment: @troyanfoe, yes, that was it! There is no more errors. Thank you.